# Ошибка bound method в классах (Python)

Tags: python, классы, методы

```
class Point():
def __init__(self, name, weight):
    self.name = name
    self.weight = weight
    self.lst = []
    self.distance = []    
def ggg(self):
    return self.lst.append(1)
```

После запуска кода:

```
a = Point('Pnt', 3)
a.ggg
```

Вызывает следующее исключение:

```
<bound method Point.ggg of <__main__.Point object at 0x0000000009620198>>
```

В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: попробуйте `ggg()`

Comment: спасибо огромное, а как закрыть вопрос?

Comment: добавил ответом

Comment: "Вызывает следующее исключение" это не исключение, это содержимое поля `a.ggg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы функция сработала, необходимо вызвать `__call__()`.

Вам необходимо указать `ggg()`

```
a = Point('Pnt', 3)
a.ggg()
```